# Write DirectShow Filter Without Using Windows SDK

Tags: com, sdk, webcam, directshow, com-object

I wanna write a **"DriectShow Source Filter"** for using webcam.

But I would know is the any way not using **"Windows SDK"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create a DirectShow filter without using Windows SDK base classes. A filter is nothing but a COM class implementing a set of COM interfaces, some of which are mandatory (`IBaseFilter`, `IPin`) and other are optional. SDK BaseClasses are helpers to give a quick start but if you want to do it from fresh - it's absolutely possible.

Answer (score 1):

Really, you are do not need to write DirectShow source filter to use webcam... Only IBaseFilter is required.

Windows SDK can help you to enumerate devices, webcam output video formats and so on, that's mean that for a real development Baseclasses is required (you can copy Baseclasses from Windows SDK).